# How to prevent R8 from removing public Compose Preview methods in release builds?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, proguard, android-r8

I'm using [airbnb/Showkase](https://github.com/airbnb/Showkase) library for collecting all previews into a catalog and was exploring the idea of putting an entry point to that catalog browser activity somewhere in admin settings page in production release builds of the app.

When I run a debug build, Showkase does collect all compose preview methods and displays them. But in release builds those methods get removed and hence nothing to display in catalog.

Is there a way to make R8 keep Compose Preview methods in release builds? Maybe a certain proguard rule?

Comment: Usually developers want to make sure that their previews are _not_ include in the release app, see https://issuetracker.google.com/301414595 and https://issuetracker.google.com/262333722. Without having tested you might be able to use something like this rule: `-keep class * { @androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview <methods>; }`. Not sure if that will give what you want, but it will retain the methods annotated with `@Preview`.

Comment: Sorry the suggested keep rule will keep way too much, please try `-keepclasseswithmembers class * { @androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview <methods>; }`instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme of the Showkase library mentions about adding the following rule when using Proguard:

```
-keep public class * extends com.airbnb.android.showkase.models.ShowkaseProvider
```

There should be no need to additionally keep all Preview annotated methods.